# Pause FileSystemWatcher during action

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I have this PowerShell Script that monitors if a file has been saved inside a folder, and then does a call to a relay to control traffic lights. When a new image is found, the traffic light goes to red, waits 60 seconds and then goes back to green.

As is to be expected - when during those 60 seconds a new file is added to this folder, it goes into the queue - so when the lights go back to green, they switch back to red for 60 seconds.

What is the cleanest way to stop the filesystemwatcher when a file is created, and restart it?
Stopping the FileSystemWatcher is no problem, when I dispose of the $FileSystemWatcher - but restarting it doesn't work. Also I would like to be the code as least redundant if possible, without copying all the FSW code inside my Action (if possible)

```
Write-Host "Auto Relay Change On Detection"
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
$settingsFile = "$PSScriptRoot\settings.json"
$j = Get-Content -Raw -Path $settingsFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$PathToMonitor = $j.imageFolder

If(!(test-path $PathToMonitor))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $PathToMonitor
}

$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path  = $PathToMonitor
$FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true

# make sure the watcher emits events
$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# define the code that should execute when a file change is detected
$Action = {
    $details = $event.SourceEventArgs
    $Name = $details.Name
    $FullPath = $details.FullPath
    $OldFullPath = $details.OldFullPath
    $OldName = $details.OldName
    $ChangeType = $details.ChangeType
    $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
    $text = "{0} was {1} at {2}" -f $FullPath, $ChangeType, $Timestamp

    # you can also execute code based on change type here
    switch ($ChangeType)
    {
        'Changed' { "CHANGE" }
        'Created' { "CREATED"
            $text = "File {0} was created." -f $Name
            Write-Host $text -ForegroundColor Yellow  
            Write-Host  "Relay = detected at $(Get-Date)" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
            #DO API CALL
            $timeout = $j.timer
            Start-Sleep -s $timeout
            #DO API CALL
            Write-Host  "Relay = default at $(Get-Date)" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
        }
        'Deleted' { "DELETED" }
        'Renamed' { "RENAMED" }
        default { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor White }
    }
}

# add event handlers
$handlers = . {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Created -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSCreate
}

try
{
    do
    {
        Wait-Event -Timeout 1
        ##Write-Host "." -NoNewline
        
    } while ($true)
}
finally
{
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSCreate
    $handlers | Remove-Job
    $FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
    $FileSystemWatcher.Dispose()
    "Event Handler disabled."
}
```

Comment: Set a flag when starting the 60 seconds. If the flag is true, bail out of your action as the first statement. There is no reason to start and stop the watcher, if you just ignore its trigger.

Comment: That's a good idea, but ( how I tested this,) my flag is always true - because it has to be reset after the second API call, so new images triggers the relay again. So after the sleep, flag gets set back to 1, and only read when the rest of the watchers queue is processed.

Comment: Thinking about it, it's probably Start-Sleep that is a wrong choice here, because the whole script gets paused, not just the watcher/relay control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Action = {
    try {
        $FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
        $details = $event.SourceEventArgs
        $Name = $details.Name
        $FullPath = $details.FullPath
        $OldFullPath = $details.OldFullPath
        $OldName = $details.OldName
        $ChangeType = $details.ChangeType
        $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
        $text = "{0} was {1} at {2}" -f $FullPath, $ChangeType, $Timestamp

        # you can also execute code based on change type here
        switch ($ChangeType)
        {
            'Changed' { "CHANGE" }
            'Created' { "CREATED"
                $text = "File {0} was created." -f $Name
                Write-Host $text -ForegroundColor Yellow  
                Write-Host  "Relay = detected at $(Get-Date)" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
                #DO API CALL
                $timeout = $j.timer
                Start-Sleep -s $timeout
                #DO API CALL
                Write-Host  "Relay = default at $(Get-Date)" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
            }
            'Deleted' { "DELETED" }
            'Renamed' { "RENAMED" }
            default { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor White }
        }
    } finally {
        $FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Did a fix that works a bit like yours. `
'Created' { "CREATED" 
$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = [bool] 0
#DO API CALL 
$timeout = $j.timer    
Start-Sleep -s $timeout      
#DO API CALL
Write-Host  "Relay = default at $(Get-Date)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = [bool] 1 
}
`
But yours seems cleaner. Thanks!